# Python Multiprocessing script runs slower than original

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I read a lot of threads on StackOverFlow to try to understand why is my multiprocessing not working properly.

I need to get IPs from a file, process them and then write them to a file. My processing involves a lot of search through dictionaries and is the part that is the most time consuming.

To troubleshoot, I made my function sleep for a 1/10 of a second on **both** of my scripts (i.e. the regular script and the multiprocessing one) and when I do, my multiprocessing script actually works 5 times faster. With that, I can conclude that my multiprocessing is actually working.

The following code runs 5x faster (concidering I add the `time.sleep(0.1)` line on both of my scripts):

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import time

def main(argv):
    *bunch of code calling processFunction*

def processFunction():
    pool = Pool(10)
    results = pool.map(processIP, ipList)
    print(results)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def processIP():
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The original code involves a **for** loop instead of multiprocessing.
My problem is that if I remove `time.sleep(0.1)` (on both of them) my script actually takes 2 or 3 seconds more than the original.
Do you have any idea why?

Thank you in advance for your help

PS: I know that i'm actually using multithreading. The script is suppose to handle a list of approximately 25k IPs

Comment: A lot of context switching and locking (GIL) between the _threads_ makes things slower. With `sleep` multiple threads could sleep in parallel compared to single thread variant. In best case 10 thread could sleep parallel and then process each an IP compared to sleeping 10 times for 10 IPs in single thread mode.

Comment: @MichaelButscher actually, the `processIP()` function is light (takes less than a 1/10 of a second) but i have to repeat it a LOT of times. What could I do to make it faster if the multithreading is not the solution?

Comment: Use real processes (as many as you have CPU cores) and cut the IP list into chunks of e.g 50 addresses which are then handled by a single process at once instead of communicating for each single IP.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you very much, it works! How can I set your comment as an answer?

Comment: You are using the `dummy` module which is an interface to multi-threading with the API of the multi-processing module. You should use real multi-processing instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python (at least CPython implementation) isn't good at multi*threading* because of the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) which prevents many operations from working really in parallel. One exception is `sleep`ing which can be done efficiently.

Therefore `multiprocessing` exists. But the `multiprocessing.dummy` is just a fallback to multithreading which is meant only to make code work that relies on multiprocessing on a system that doesn't support it.

As your code just does multithreading it is effective when sleeping but not when working.

To make the code more effective if a single working unit (here: processing an IP) doesn't need much time but the number of units is high, you should create chunks of e.g. 50 IPs which are processed at once by a child process to reduce overhead of communication between parent and children processes.